# python 2.7 XML lxml namespace prefix attribute issues

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml, xml-namespaces

So, I've seen a lot of answers that target this question, but they don't explicitly state how to adjust the namespace prefix when it changes throughout the span of the XML document.

**What I have:**

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <ns0:Description xmlns:ns0="http://purl.org/NET/FOO">
    </ns0:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**What I want:**

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.org/NET/FOO">
    </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

*To clarify*, I want the child SubElement's `xmlns:rdfs` to be `rdf:about`.

**What used to work in Python2.5:**

```
rdf_description = SubElement(
    root,
    '{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description',
    {'rdf:about':vocab_namespace}
)
```

**What I've tried in Python2.7:**

```
register_namespace('rdf', 'rdf:about')
rdf_description = SubElement(
    root,
    '{http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#}Description',
    nsmap={'rdf': rdf_url}
)
```

... *well* I've tried that and permutations of such too long to list (this is how I currently have it), but I can't seem to shift the bits how I need them.

If a true lxml ninja could step down from their palace of pleasure and instruct this newb, I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
RDFNS = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
root = lxml.etree.Element('{%s}RDF' % RDFNS, nsmap={'rdf': RDFNS})
rdf_description = lxml.etree.SubElement(
    root,
    '{%s}Description' % RDFNS,
    {"{%s}about" % RDFNS: "http://purl.org/NET/FOO"})
```

Checking output:

```
>>> print lxml.etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.org/NET/FOO"/>
</rdf:RDF>

>>>
```